# VNC on OSX: screen resolution

Tags: macos, vnc

I have a desktop with a high-res display and laptop with a low-res display.

Can the laptop log into the desktop and display its screen as if it were low-res? -- as if I had a low-res second monitor connected to the desktop.

I'm not talking about shrinking the pixels or cutting off the screen with scrollbars (as is default in Chicken of the VNC)

Comment: I guess, if you're using a "stupid" protocol like VNC, then no. What systems are your laptop and your desktop? You nowhere mention which one is the OS X machine or if both are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OS-X Screen Sharing (assuming both machines are OS-X), then yes, the laptop will show a shrunk view of the desktop's screen.